# Getting error trying to scrape data from FiveThirtyEight

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from [FiveThirtyEight's presidential approval rating](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/) to get the dates, pollsters, sample sizes, and percentages into a data frame in R. My first attempt was an approach using html_nodes:

```
pres_approval <- read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/")

pres_approval <- pres_approval %>%
                     html_nodes(css = "table") %>%
                     nth(2) %>%
                     html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Which returned

> Error in nodes_duplicated(nodes) : Expecting an external pointer: [type=NULL].`

And then again using the Selector Gadget:

```
 pres_approval <- read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/")`

 pres_approval <- pres_approval %>%
                      html_nodes(css = "td , .heat-map , .pollster a") %>%
                      nth(2) %>%
                      html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`
```

Which returned

> Error in html_table.xml_node(., header = TRUE, fill = TRUE) : html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE`

What can I do from here?

Comment: I only see one table on that page, so I think `nth(2)` should be `nth(1)`.

Comment: They have alot of data here: https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data (not sure if this is there, tho)

Answer (score 2):

They generally load data asynchronously via XHR requests which you can see if you open Developer Tools in your browser and re-load the page. In Network -> XHR you'll see lots of lovely JSON:

[image]

I don't know which one you want (I skimmed the Q) but you can get all the main JSON files easily:

```
polls <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/polls.json")

str(polls, 1)
## 'data.frame': 3401 obs. of  14 variables:
##  $ id           : int  77261 77265 77272 77249 77257 77266 77596 77246 77263 77253 ...
##  $ subgroup     : chr  "All polls" "All polls" "All polls" "All polls" ...
##  $ sampleSize   : int  1992 1500 1190 1043 1500 2692 1712 1500 1500 1991 ...
##  $ population   : chr  "rv" "a" "rv" "rv" ...
##  $ weight       : num  0.946 0.245 1.645 1.166 0.639 ...
##  $ grade        : chr  "B-" "B" "A-" "B" ...
##  $ multiversions: logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
##  $ url          : chr  "http://www.politico.com/story/2017/01/poll-voters-liked-trumps-inaugural-address-234148" "http://www.gallup.com/poll/201617/gallup-daily-trump-job-approval.aspx" "https://poll.qu.edu/national/release-detail?ReleaseID=2415" "http://www.publicpolicypolling.com/pdf/2015/PPP_Release_National_12617.pdf" ...
##  $ created_at   : chr  "2017-01-23" "2017-01-23" "2017-01-26" "2017-01-25" ...
##  $ startDate    : chr  "2017-01-20" "2017-01-20" "2017-01-20" "2017-01-23" ...
##  $ endDate      : chr  "2017-01-22" "2017-01-22" "2017-01-25" "2017-01-24" ...
##  $ pollster     : chr  "Morning Consult" "Gallup" "Quinnipiac University" "Public Policy Polling" ...
##  $ tracking     : chr  "" "T" "" "" ...
##  $ answers      :List of 3401

approval <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/approval.json")

str(approval, 1)
## 'data.frame': 2751 obs. of  9 variables:
##  $ date               : chr  "2017-01-23" "2017-01-23" "2017-01-23" "2017-01-24" ...
##  $ future             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
##  $ subgroup           : chr  "Adults" "All polls" "Voters" "Adults" ...
##  $ approve_estimate   : chr  "45" "45.46693" "46" "45" ...
##  $ approve_hi         : chr  "51.1347" "50.88971" "52.29238" "50.98562" ...
##  $ approve_lo         : chr  "38.8653" "40.04416" "39.70762" "39.01438" ...
##  $ disapprove_estimate: chr  "45" "41.26452" "37" "45.74659" ...
##  $ disapprove_hi      : chr  "51.1347" "46.68729" "43.29238" "51.73221" ...
##  $ disapprove_lo      : chr  "38.8653" "35.84175" "30.70762" "39.76097" ...

historic_approval <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/historical-approval.json")

str(historic_approval, 1)
## 'data.frame': 26001 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ president          : chr  "Harry S. Truman" "Harry S. Truman" "Harry S. Truman" "Harry S. Truman" ...
##  $ date               : chr  "1945-06-06" "1945-06-07" "1945-06-08" "1945-06-09" ...
##  $ days               : int  55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 ...
##  $ subgroup           : chr  "All polls" "All polls" "All polls" "All polls" ...
##  $ approve_estimate   : chr  "87" "87" "87" "87" ...
##  $ disapprove_estimate: chr  "3" "3" "3" "3" ...
```

I'd run the resultant data frame(s) through `readr::type_convert()` to get better types.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @hrbrmstr is the cleaner way to get the table you need. The tables by extracting the JSON file are ready to be used for any purpose.

I get the table when I reproduced your example using nth(1) instead of nth(2).

Here is an example with Biden's approval ratings:

```
pres_approval <- read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/biden-approval-rating")

pres_approval <- pres_approval %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "polls", " " ))]') %>%
  nth(1) %>%
  html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

print(pres_approval)

```
# A tibble: 15 x 15
   ``    DATES   POLLSTER    GRADE SAMPLE SAMPLE WEIGHT APPROVE APPROVE DISAPPROVE DISAPPROVE
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <lgl>      <chr>     
 1 •     Jun. 1~ Ipsos       "B-"  1,002  A        0.86 52%     42%     NA         50%       
 2 •     Jun. 1~ YouGov      "B+"  1,500  A        1.42 48%     43%     NA         49%       
 3 •     Jun. 9~ Morning Co~ "B"   15,000 A        1.95 53%     39%     NA         52%       
 4 •     Jun. 1~ AP-NORC     ""    1,125  A        1.51 55%     44%     NA         51%       
 5 •     Jun. 9~ Monmouth U~ "A"   810    A        1.53 48%     43%     NA         48%       
 6 •     Jun. 1~ Ipsos       "B-"  1,002  A        0.86 52%     42%     NA         51%       
 7 •     Jun. 1~ Rasmussen ~ "B"   1,500  LV       1.3  51%     48%     NA         54%       
 8 •     Jun. 1~ YouGov      "B+"  1,500  A        1.42 48%     43%     NA         49%       
 9 •     Jun. 9~ Morning Co~ "B"   15,000 A        1.8  53%     39%     NA         52%       
10 •     Jun. 1~ AP-NORC     ""    1,125  A        1.51 55%     44%     NA         51%       
11 •     Jun. 1~ Rasmussen ~ "B"   1,500  LV       1.3  51%     48%     NA         54%       
12 •     Jun. 1~ YouGov      "B+"  1,305  RV       1.38 48%     45%     NA         49%       
13 •     Jun. 1~ Rasmussen ~ "B"   1,500  LV       0.77 49%     49%     NA         52%       
14 •     Jun. 1~ Global Str~ "B/C" 1,001  RV       1    52%     44%     NA         52%       
15 •     Jun. 9~ Monmouth U~ "A"   758    RV       1.45 49%     43%     NA         50%
```

There is only one table, so you should have nth set to 1.

If you look closely, you see the data table needs some simple wrangling of renaming columns and getting rid of other empty ones. Also, the table contains only 15 rows.

To get the full table you can use RSelenium to expand the table and capture it fully.